# Programmatically merge rows of a huge file for NLP

Tags: python, nlp

[image]

I need to use the Google ngram corpus (http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) that has data of frequency of n-grams appeared in a book year by year.

File format: Each of the files below is compressed tab-separated data and line has the following format:

```
ngram TAB year TAB match_count TAB volume_count NEWLINE.
```

I wrote a code to retrieve the frequency of my input ngram

[image]

And the code is written as :

```
file = 'D:\Chrome Downloads\googlebooks-eng-all-4gram-20120701-aj\googlebooks-eng-all-4gram-20120701-aj'

z = []
counter = 0
freq = 0
with open(file, 'rt', encoding='UTF8') as input:

    for line in input:
        if(counter == 150):
            break
        if('Ajax and Achilles ?' == (line.strip().split('\t')[0])):
        #else:
           print(line.strip().split('\t'))
           freq += int((line.strip().split('\t')[2]))

print('Frequency :', freq)
```

This worked well only because `Ajax and Achilles` appears on the top part of the corpus (the counter stops it). When I try to search for an ngram that appears later, it takes forever.

The problem with using this corpus to get the frequency of an n-gram is that I have to look through the whole corpus regardless.

So, I was thinking of merging the rows ignoring the year and summing up the frequency.

Is this a valid idea? If so, how can I do this programmatically?

It not, what is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do split the lines multiple times and, of course, reading the entire file for each ngram you want to check is not ideal. Why don't you write out the total frequencies for each ngram to another file. Guessing that this google file of yours is enormous, you probably cannot easily collect counts into a single data structrue before writing them out. Relying on the file being sorted by ngram already, you can write the new file without loading the whole corpus at once:

```
from csv import reader, writer
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

get_ngram = itemgetter(0)

with open(file, 'rt', encoding='UTF8') as input, open('freq.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as output:
    r = reader(input, delimiter='\t')
    w = writer(output, delimiter='\t')
    for ngram, rows in groupby(r, key=get_ngram):
    # for i, (ngram, rows) in enumerate(groupby(r, key=get_ngram)):
        # the i and enumerate is just for the loop not being too silent ...
        freq = sum(int(row[2]) for row in rows)
        w.writerow((ngram, freq))
        # if not i % 10000:   # ... and give you some idea what's happening
            # print('Processing ngram {}')
```

The [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) classes just take over the csv parsing and writing part. The `csv.reader` is a lazy iterator over lists of strings. The [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) groups the rows produced by the csv reader by the first token using the `key` parameter with an appropriate function. This is done using the [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) just to avoid some clunky `key=lambda x: x[0]`. `groupby` produces pairs of the key value and the elements of the grouped iterator that have said value. Then it sums the frequencies for these grouped rows and writes only the ngram and frequency to the file using the `csv.writer`.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I am getting an error on: w.writerow((ngram, freq)) UnsupportedOperation: not writable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you use the `'w'` flag on the output file?

Comment: Yes i just directly copied your answer

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Of course you have to use the output file for the `w` writer. I edited my answer.

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe it only takes like a second to parse such a large corpus. Thank you so much! Could you please explain how the code works though? I don't get how it tries to eliminate the 'year' and only parse the 'frequency' of the ngram. And I also want to know what makes it so fast. Thanks again!

Comment: @Dawn17 Added some explanation. You can see that the `writerow` call only writes the ngram itself (as returned by `itemgetter(0)`) and the sum of the frequencies in the ngram's rows (`sum(... row[2] ...)`).  That's where the other information is discarded.

Comment: Thanks!! So, if I want to use this new file to find the frequency, will it still take long if I am looking for the n-gram that appears at the very end of the file? Is there an efficient way to handle this, or is this the best?